# What is the correct schemaVersion for Azure SDK 2.6

Tags: azure, sdk, azure-sdk-.net

Anyone knows what is the correct "date" in the schemaVersion  for CloudConfiguration's ServiceDefinition schema?

I just updated the Azure SDK from 2.4 to 2.6, but the "Upgrade" button in CloudConfiguration project fails to work (seems a lot of things that Microsoft published have to be fixed with Notepad).
So I am about to manually update the SDK in the .csdef file with Notepad++ (seems a lot of things that Microsoft published have to be fixed with Notepad), as this is what this button did the last time.
But smart enough, MS decided to put some date in the version number, so I do not have big chances to guess it.

Does anyone have successfully installed Azure SDK 2.6?

If so, please give me the first line of the .csdef file.
Mine states:

```
<ServiceDefinition name="CloudConfiguration" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" schemaVersion="2014-06.2.4">
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is `2015-04.2.6`. BTW, you could have just created a new Cloud Services project and checked it there only :).

Comment: Thanks for the hint. 
Seems the file was read-only, that's why the Upgrade button failed to "upgrade". 
Anyway - it does not excuse MS for putting a date in the version value, which is not publicly available, and is not possible to guess.

Comment: thanks!
Any idea how to make the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager 3.1.0 to work? It does not work even in a new project ( I tried your idea )

Comment: One thing I noticed with `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager 3.1.0` is that they have changed the namespace from `Microsoft.WindowsAzure` to `Microsoft.Azure`. In my project where I upgraded from 2.4 to 2.6, that was the only change I had to make in the code. Other than that, no changes were required. You may want to post the problems you're facing as a new question.

Comment: Yes, they changed the namespace. We refactored our code, but it always returned nulls. The problem was with the Azure Emulator though. Thanks.